# How to configure an OpenTracing Tracer to push data to Prometheus/Grafana in Java

Tags: java, prometheus, opentracing

I have a Spring Boot app using OpenTracing and I would like to push its data to Prometheus, so I can query all metrics via Grafana (like in this tutorial https://www.hawkular.org/blog/2017/06/26/opentracing-appmetrics.html).

The problem is, I haven't found any consistent solution to do this, all the examples that I have found so far are outdated, deprecated or lacks documentation.

Ideally, I am looking for some solution which returns an instance of io.opentracing.Tracer, similar to what Jaeger does:

```
        Tracer tracer = new JaegerTracer.Builder("couchbase")
            .withReporter(new RemoteReporter.Builder()
                    .withSender(new UdpSender(AGENT_HOST, 6831, 0))
                    .build())
            .withSampler(new ConstSampler(true))
            .withScopeManager(new AutoFinishScopeManager())
            .withMetricsFactory(metricsFactory)
            .build();
```

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that tracing data (spans) are not the same as "metrics", although there could be some overlap in some cases. I recommend the following blog post on what is the purpose of each, including logging:

https://peter.bourgon.org/blog/2017/02/21/metrics-tracing-and-logging.html

That said, there is the OpenTracing library mentioned in the blog post you linked, called [opentracing-contrib/java-metrics](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-metrics). It allows you to pick specific spans and record them as data points (metrics). It works as a decorator of a concrete tracer, so, your spans would reach a concrete backend like Jaeger and, additionally, create data points based on the configured spans. The data points are then reported via [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/), which can be configured to expose this data in Prometheus format.

> The problem is, I haven't found any consistent solution to do this, all the examples that I have found so far are outdated, deprecated or lacks documentation.

Please, open an issue on the `java-metrics` repository with the problems you are facing.